# How to prevent BODY horizontal scrolling when modal dialog is open in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, modal-dialog

I have a document (a table) and a modal dialog for which I dynamically generate the content. The modal content is scrollable and there is a dismiss button. When the modal is open, I want to disable the underlying document from scrolling in both the vertical and horizontal, just as the browser (Chrome) does when a right click context menu is open.

I Googled the issue and searched here. All the questions I found address vertical scrolling and say to set **overflow: hidden** on the `<body>` tag. A couple say to add **position: fixed**, and a couple say to set the CSS on the `<html>` tag.

Setting **overflow: hidden** on `<body>` works fine to disable the document vertical scrolling. I tried all the other combinations of the above and nothing worked to disable horizontal scrolling. (Further, **position: fixed** screws up the positioning of the modal on the page.)

The relevant JS I have, on modal open, is:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' );
el[0].style.overflowY = 'hidden';
el[0].style.overflowX = 'hidden';
```

and on modal close:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' );
el[0].style.overflowX = 'auto';
el[0].style.overflowY = 'auto';
```

There is a pen [Table Play](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/oLLeRX) at CodePen with all the code for the project. I didn't reproduce the code here because it is extensive and it seems immaterial, but I'll certainly add any further code or information anyone requests.

I'm working in JavaScript, in which I'm a novice autodidact. I'm open to a jQuery solution but I have only a tiny familiarity with the syntax so would need specific direction.

Thank you for your interest in my question and for your time.

Comment: If setting the `overflow` of `body` to 'hidden' didn't help it means that another element is allowing the scroll so if you have some easy guess, go for it and change that element's `overflow`.I think the easiest solution would be to add an overlay

Comment: "it means that another element is allowing the scroll" -- that was it. The underlying document is a table that is responsive by **overflowX: auto**. I set that to hidden and the horizontal scroll was stopped. Thanks so much.